# How to build initrd without dmraid-driver on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, initrd

I would like to follow this piece of [advice on `mdadm` Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm#Known_problems) (to get `mdadm` & RAID working on my Karmic workstation):

> To solve this problem, you need to
>   build a new initrd without the
>   dmraid-driver. The following command
>   does this on a system with the
>   "2.6.18-8.1.6.el5"-kernel:
>
> `mkinitrd --omit-dmraid /boot/NO_DMRAID_initrd-2.6.18[..].img 2.6.18[..]`

However, [turns out](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1039735) Ubuntu uses `mkinitramfs`; `initrd-tools` (and thus `mkinitrd`) is no longer available for it.

Can I use `mkinitramfs` to build initrd omitting dmraid? The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/mkinitramfs.8.html) does not mention such option at all. Or if not `mkinitramfs`, some other way to do it on Ubuntu 9.10?

(Follow-up to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/101630/creating-a-raid1-partition-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu).)

Comment: Nor does `update-initramfs` man page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/update-initramfs.8.html) help much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha! It occurred to me to simply try removing the dmraid Ubuntu packages to see if it helps, and it seems that it did.

This is what I did (after finding out what the packages are):

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid libdmraid1.0.0.rc15
```

I then updated initrd like this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-17-generic
```

Now, after reboot, `mdmadm` doesn't give the "Device or resource busy" error message anymore. :-)

**NB**: I'm not sure if `update-initramfs -u` was necessary (but it certainly didn't do any harm either).

Comment: This also solved my original problem (not being able to set up a RAID1 partition); for details, see: http://superuser.com/questions/101630/creating-a-raid1-partition-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu/102111#102111