# How to get an inactive RAID device working again?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

After booting, my RAID1 device (`/dev/md_d0` *) sometimes goes in some funny state and I cannot mount it.

<sup>* Originally I created `/dev/md0` but it has somehow changed itself into `/dev/md_d0`.</sup>

```
# mount /opt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md_d0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (could this be the IDE device where you in fact use
       ide-scsi so that sr0 or sda or so is needed?)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

The RAID device appears to be **inactive** somehow:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] 
                [raid4] [raid10] 
md_d0 : inactive sda4[0](S)
      241095104 blocks

# mdadm --detail /dev/md_d0
mdadm: md device /dev/md_d0 does not appear to be active.
```

Question is, **how to make the device active again** (using `mdmadm`, I presume)?

(Other times it's alright (active) after boot, and I can mount it manually without problems. But it still won't mount automatically even though I have it in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/md_d0        /opt           ext4    defaults        0       0
```

So a bonus question: **what should I do to make the RAID device automatically mount at `/opt` at boot time?**)

This is an Ubuntu 9.10 workstation. [Background info about my RAID setup in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/101630/creating-a-raid1-partition-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu).

**Edit**: My `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` looks like this. I've never touched this file, at least by hand.

```
# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR <my mail address>

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 27 Jan 2010 17:14:36 +0200
```

In `/proc/partitions` the last entry is `md_d0` at least now, after reboot, when the device happens to be active again. (I'm not sure if it would be the same when it's inactive.)

**Resolution**: as [Jimmy Hedman suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/117824/how-to-get-an-inactive-raid-device-working-again/118251#118251), I took the output of `mdadm --examine --scan`:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=de8fbd92[...]
```

and added it in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, which seems to have fixed the main problem. After changing `/etc/fstab` to use `/dev/md0` again (instead of `/dev/md_d0`), the RAID device also gets automatically mounted!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For your bonus question:

```
mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Comment: Ok, `mdadm --examine --scan` produced `ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=...` (Note the md0 instead of md_d0!) I put that in the mdadm.conf file (manually, because the was some problem with sudo and `>>` ("permission denied"), and sudo *is* required) and also updated fstab to use md0 (not md_d0) again. Now I don't seem to run into the "inactive" problem anymore *and* the RAID device mounts automatically at /opt upon booting. So thanks!

Comment: The reason you had problems with `sudo ... >> mdadm.conf` is that the shell opens the redirected files before sudo runs. The command `su -c '.... >> mdadm.conf'` should work.

Comment: I ran sudo su and ran this as root. It went but unfortunately because I'm me and not everyone else in the world, this didn't start or mount jack sh*t

Answer (score 12):

I have found that I have to add the array manually in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` in order to make Linux mount it on reboot. Otherwise I get exactly what you have here - `md_d1`-devices that are inactive etc.

The conf-file should look like below - i.e. one `ARRAY`-line for each md-device. In my case the new arrays were missing in this file, but if you have them listed this is probably not a fix to your problem.

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 UUID=f10f5f96:106599e0:a2f56e56:f5d3ad6d
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=aa591bbe:bbbec94d:a2f56e56:f5d3ad6d
```

Add one array per md-device, and add them after the comment included above, or if no such comment exists, at the end of the file. You get the UUIDs by doing `sudo mdadm -E --scan`:

```
$ sudo mdadm -E --scan
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=3 UUID=f10f5f96:106599e0:a2f56e56:f5d3ad6d
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=aa591bbe:bbbec94d:a2f56e56:f5d3ad6d
```

As you can see you can pretty much just copy the output from the scan-result into the file.

I run ubuntu desktop 10.04 LTS, and as far as I remember this behavior differs from the server version of Ubuntu, however it was such a long time ago I created my md-devices on the server I may be wrong. It may also be that I just missed some option.

Anyway, adding the array in the conf-file seems to do the trick. I've run the above raid 1 and raid 5 for years with no problems.

Comment: So essentially you're saying the same thing as the currently accepted answer, just more verbosely? :) Still, +1, nice first post.

Answer (score 9):

**Warning:** First of all let me say that the below (due to the use of "--force") seems risky to me, and if you have irrecoverable data I'd recommend making copies of the partitions involved before  you start trying any of the things below.  However, this worked for me.

I had the same problem, with an array showing up as inactive, and nothing I did including the "mdadm --examine --scan >/etc/mdadm.conf", as suggested by others here, helped at all.

In my case, when it tried to start the RAID-5 array after a drive replacement, it was saying that it was dirty (via `dmesg`):

```
md/raid:md2: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
md/raid:md2: device sda4 operational as raid disk 0
md/raid:md2: device sdd4 operational as raid disk 3
md/raid:md2: device sdc4 operational as raid disk 2
md/raid:md2: device sde4 operational as raid disk 4
md/raid:md2: allocated 5334kB
md/raid:md2: cannot start dirty degraded array.
```

Causing it to show up as inactive in `/proc/mdstat`:

```
md2 : inactive sda4[0] sdd4[3] sdc4[2] sde4[5]
      3888504544 blocks super 1.2
```

I did find that all the devices had the same events on them, except for the drive I had replaced (`/dev/sdb4`):

```
[root@nfs1 sr]# mdadm -E /dev/sd*4 | grep Event
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb4.
         Events : 8448
         Events : 8448
         Events : 8448
         Events : 8448
```

However, the array details showed that it had 4 out of 5 devices available:

```
[root@nfs1 sr]# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
[...]
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 4
[...]
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
[...]
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      inactive dirty  /dev/sda4
       2       8       36        2      inactive dirty  /dev/sdc4
       3       8       52        3      inactive dirty  /dev/sdd4
       5       8       68        4      inactive dirty  /dev/sde4
```

(The above is from memory on the "State" column, I can't find it in my scroll-back buffer).

I was able to resolve this by stopping the array and then re-assembling it:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md2
mdadm -A --force /dev/md2 /dev/sd[acde]4
```

At that point the array was up, running with 4 of the 5 devices, and I was able to add the replacement device and it's rebuilding.  I'm able to access the file-system without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was having issues with Ubuntu 10.04 where an error in FStab prevented the server from booting.

I ran this command as mentioned in the above solutions:

```
mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

This will append the results from "mdadm --examine --scan" to "/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf"

In my case, this was:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=2660925e:6d2c43a7:4b95519e:b6d110e7 name=localhost:0
```

This is a fakeraid 0. My command in **/etc/fstab** for automatically mounting is:

```
/dev/md0 /home/shared/BigDrive ext3 defaults,nobootwait,nofail 0 0
```

The important thing here is that you have "nobootwait" and "nofail". Nobootwait will skip any system messages which are preventing you from booting. In my case, this was on a remote server so it was essential.

Hope this will help some people.

Comment: This is what did it for me. I have my RAID drives attached via a PCI express SATA card, so I'm guessing at boot time the system couldn't see those drives yet.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to get the array to run assuming there is no hardware problem and you have enough drives/partitions to start the array is the following:

```
md20 : inactive sdf1[2](S)
      732442488 blocks super 1.2

 sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md20  --run
```

It could be that for whatever reason the array is fine but something prevented it from starting or building.  In my case this was because mdadm didn't know the original array name was md127 and all drives were unplugged for that array.  When replugging I had to manually assemble (probably a bug where mdadm thought the array was already active because of the offline old array name).

Answer (score 2):

You can activate your md device with

```
mdadm -A /dev/md_d0
```

I suppose some startup script starts too soon, before one of the RAID member was discovered or some similar problem. As a quick and dirty workaround, you should be able to add this line to /etc/rc.local :

```
mdadm -A /dev/md_d0 && mount /dev/md_d0
```

Edit : apparently your /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf still contains the old configuration name. Edit this file and replace occurences of md0 with md_d0.

Comment: Ok, on those occasions when the device *is* active after reboot, just `mount /dev/md_d0` in `/etc/rc.local` works fine. `mdadm -A /dev/md_d0` on the other hand fails with that error message in both cases (so I couldn't use it before that `&&` operator). Anyway, half of the problem seems solved so +1 for that.

Comment: Actually mdadm.conf doesn't contain any configuration name, at least directly (it does refer to `/proc/partitions` though); see the edited question. I've never touched mdadm.conf - what is the tool that autogenerates it?

Comment: For the record, removed the `/etc/rc.local` workaround as it seems I got everything working properly: http://superuser.com/questions/117824/how-to-get-an-inactive-raid-device-working-again/118251#118251 :)

Answer (score 2):

`md_d0 : inactive sda4[0](S)` looks wrong for a RAID1 array. It seems to suggest that the array has no active devices and one spare device <sup><sub>(indicated by the (S), you would see (F) there for a failed device and nothing for an OK/active device)</sub></sup> - for a RAID1 array that isn't running degraded there should be at least two OK/active devices <sup><sub>(and for a degraded array, at least one OK/active device)</sub></sup> and you can't activate a RAID1 array with no none-failed not-spare devices (as spares do not contain a copy of the data until they are made active when another drive fails). If I'm reading that `/proc/mdstat` output right, you'll not be able to activate the array in its current state.

Do you have any physical drives in the machine that have failed to spin-up? Does `ls /dev/sd*` list all the drives and partitions that you would normally expect to see on that machine?

Comment: Seems I cannot reproduce the inactive situation any more, after following the advice in Jimmy's answer (seems like that anyway after a few reboots)... Which is nice :) Thanks in any case!

Comment: I brought the question of this state to the Linux RAID mailing list, and got this response: https://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg61352.html

Comment: As I just wrote [here](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/676-how-to-fix-linux-mdadm-inactive-array#!/ccomment-comment=175), `echo active > /sys/block/md0/md/array_state` worked for me, bringing making my RAID show up as RAID1 with missing disk again instead of RAID0 with spare-only.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem... my server would not mount md2 after I had grown theassociated devices partitions. On reading this thread I found that the md2 RAID device had a new UUID and the machine was trying to use the old one.

As suggested... using 'md2' output from

```
mdadm --examine --scan
```

I edited `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and replaced the old UUID line with the one output from above command and my problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

When you pretend to do something with `/dev/md[012346789}` it goes to `/dev/md{126,127...}`.
`/dev/md0` continues mounted at `/dev/md126` or `/dev/md127` you have to:

umount `/dev/md127`
or
umount `/dev/md126`.

This is temporary to let you execute commands and some applications without stopping your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by the OS (Debian) booting to "maintainance mode" because an fstab entry was not available at boot.

Commenting out the missing fstab entry and rebooting will fix the issue in this case.

If you can't do that for whatever reason, running

```
# mdadm --run /dev/md127
```

also fixed the issue.

Ref: https://ahelpme.com/linux/inactive-array-mdadm-cannot-get-array-info-for-dev-md126/

In my case, I had only 1 drive attached of a 2 drive RAID1 pair.